# HTML output encoding in Freemarker

Tags: encoding, freemarker

I am working on an issue raised by the security team about a possible XSS attack on a few input fields on our form. Our freemarker page has the following code.

```
<#assign zipcode = someObject.getInfo().getZipCodeFirstFive()>
```

I read up on HTML encoding and it talks about adding ?html at the end but I couldn't find the freemarker syntax anywhere. So, could I do something like

```
<#assign zipcode = (someObject.getInfo().getZipCodeFirstFive())?html>
```

to make it output encoded?

Comment: I don't have an environment to try this out, that's why I had to post this here.

Comment: Actually, you do have an environment to try this out: http://freemarker-online.kenshoo.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be a possible syntax for this, though I would recommend two things to make it more readable:

- You don't need the extra `()`, you can just write `someObject.getInfo().getZipCodeFirstFive()?html`
- It's unrelated to escaping, but you don't need to write out getters either, so you end up with `someObject.info.zipCodeFirstFive?html`

On the longer term, I would recommend escaping by default. Before 2.3.24 that's done by surrounding each template by `<#escape x as x?html>...</#escape>`. Starting from 2.3.24 the recommended methods is auto-escaping set up globally, in the `Configuration`.

Comment: Thank you. I just showed my solution to one of my peers, and he said this isn't the correct way to do it. He said that I am doing it where the field is getting set. Instead I should be doing it on all the pages where it's getting printed to the page. I am a bit confused now.

Comment: In the example you have shown here you are escaping where the value's getting printed, which is what your peers wanted too. Where's the contradiction?

Comment: yes, we are on the same page now :) Thank you very much for your help!